# drop down does not focuses the selected value when expanded

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf-2, primefaces

I have created a drop down menu in prime faces 3. When i expand the drop down then it focuses on the first value / option. Consider the case when selected value is 2nd last in the list and is selected through scroll. Now if you want to change it and you click on the drop down then the first item of the list is focused and you will have to scroll the entire list again. Whereas simple HTML drop down list does not perform this.

my code is as follows:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="currency" value="#{createPayment.defaultCurrency}" widgetVar="currency">  
            <f:selectItems value="#{createPayment.currenciesList}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Regards,
Asad

Comment: I am not observing the same behavior on PF showcase. What browser are you using?

Comment: Actually i have customized its theme through JQuery theme builder and that is causing this behavior. If i use default theme then it works fine. If you can help in getting the class name that performs the focusing task than that will be great.